# Termcolor returning strange string of characters

Tags: python, termcolor, wordle-game

I'm trying to build my own version of Wordle, and I've gotten stuck here. This part of the code is meant to color the appropriate character green when it matches the position and letter of the secret word, and yellow when it matches the letter, but not the position. Characters which aren't contained in the secret word aren't colored.

```py
from termcolor import colored
secret = "widow"

def color(word):
    if word[0] == secret[0]:
        word = word.replace(word[0], colored(word[0], 'green'))
    if word[0] == secret[1] or secret[2] or secret[3] or secret[4]:
        word = word.replace(word[0], colored(word[0], 'yellow'))
    if word[1] == secret[1]:
        word = word.replace(word[1], colored(word[1], 'green'))
    if word[1] == secret[0] or secret[2] or secret[3] or secret[4]:
        word = word.replace(word[1], colored(word[1], 'yellow'))
    if word[2] == secret[2]:
        word = word.replace(word[2], colored(word[2], 'green'))
    if word[2] == secret[1] or secret[0] or secret[3] or secret[4]:
        word = word.replace(word[2], colored(word[2], 'yellow'))
    if word[3] == secret[3]:
        word = word.replace(word[3], colored(word[3], 'green'))
    if word[3] == secret[1] or secret[2] or secret[0] or secret[4]:
        word = word.replace(word[3], colored(word[3], 'yellow'))
    if word[4] == secret[4]:
        word = word.replace(word[4], colored(word[4], 'green'))
    if word[4] == secret[1] or secret[2] or secret[3] or secret[0]:
        word = word.replace(word[4], colored(word[4], 'yellow'))
    return word

print(color("woiky"))
```

In this example I'm expecting "woiky" to print with a green "w" (because woiky and widow both start with a "w"), a yellow "i" and a yellow "o" (because "widow" contains both an "i" and "o", but not in those positions), but instead it prints:
[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m33m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m0m33m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m33m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m0m0m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m33m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m0m32mw[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m33m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m0m33m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m33m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m0m0m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m33m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m[33m[[0m33m[33m[[0m[33m[[0m0m0m0moiky

And all the "[" characters are yellow.

Comment: There are several problems here.  First, `word[0] == secret[1] or secret[2] or secret[3] or secret[4]` does not do what you think it does.  Python reads that as `(word[0] == secret[1]) or secret[2] or secret[3] or secret[4]`, and since `secret[2]` is always true, the expression will always be true.  Next, remember that `word.replace` replaces EVERY OCCURRENCE of that letter.  If you guess `m`, it's going to replace ALL the m's with the color sequence, even the ones in the color sequences you've already added.

Comment: How are you printing the results?  Remember the code for yellow text is `"\x1b[33m"` and going back to black is `'\x1b[30m"`.  If you're printing to a console, those codes will be interpreted.  If you save to file, you'll see the escape codes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want, in a smarter way.  I didn't want to download `termcolor`, so I provided a substitute.

```
#from termcolor import colored
secret = "widow"

def colored(a,b):
    return( f"<{b}>{a}</{b}>" )

def color(word):
    build = []
    for i,letter in enumerate(word):
        if letter == secret[i]:
            build.append( colored(letter, 'green'))
        elif letter in secret:
            build.append( colored(letter, 'yellow'))
        else:
            build.append( letter )
    return ''.join(build)

print(color("woiky"))
```